# How to calculate with Time in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

How can i calculate with Time?

I want zu Calculate the Time between 2 Timestamps, which are entered in textboxes..

[image]

Comment: (New Time - Old Time)*1440 = Difference in Minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No button needed; just use as *ControlSource* for the third textbox:

```
=CDate([Time2]-[Time1])
```

Then set the *Format* property of that textbox to a time format, for example:

```
h:nn
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the DateDiff() function to specify the date/time values and the unit that you want the result returned in.